# How to bake with Blender 2.82 and keep shading information?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, node-editor, shaders, texture-baking

I am having issues baking in blender. I'm new to blender so I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have the UV mesh unwrapped and a blank image-texture selected for it to bake to. But whenever I bake it, it always bake as a flat color with no shading. Also, I am only trying to bake the skin. I have tried the bake types, diffuse, normal, and combined and still have the same issue. I've also tried different setups with the nodes. I was able to get a white highlight around the islands of baked UV mesh by playing around with the nodes, however when I imported it into Unity, it showed up completely flat colored just like the ones I did before.

[image: Rendered Image]
[image: Shader nodes]
[image: Baked UV map - no shading]

[image: with diffuse setting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want it.
qqqqqqqqqqqqq

[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried this setting and it turned the UV mesh to be black where the flat color was, I also added a pic for the results..

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by first switching from the material view to the render view. From there I was able to see that the 3d object looked flat, so I moved the light source  in-front of the character and played around with the nodes so that I could keep my Mtoon shader and combine it with another. After I did that the 3d model started to look shaded, so I baked it with the combine but I'm pretty sure the other settings would work too. Once I imported it in Unity, it kept the shading :-D